# Read xml file with type_id opencv-image using opencv

Tags: opencv

Hey i have tried a lot search in reading xml file with type_id "opencv-image", all i am looking here is "opencv-matrix" and all help available is useless for me. 
Please help me out in reading an image matrix from xml file.

I am pasting here an upper portion of my xml file for some idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<depthImg190 type_id="opencv-image">
<width>320</width>
<height>240</height>
<origin>top-left</origin>
<layout>interleaved</layout>
<dt>w</dt>
<data>
0 0 0 0 27120 27384 27120 27120 27384 27120 27120 27120 27120 27384
27384 27664 27664 27944 27944 27664 27664 27944 27944 27944 28224
27944 27944 28224 28224 28224 28224 28520 28816 29120 29120 29120
29120 29120 29120 29120 29432 29744 30072 30072 29744 29744 30072
30072 30072 30400 30400 30736 30736 31080 31080 31080 31440 31440
31440 31440 31800 31800 31800 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 27120 27120 27120 27120 27384 27384 27384 27384 27384 27384
</depthImg190>
</opencv_storage>
```

I have used the code

```
FileStorage f;
Mat m;
f.open("temp.xml", FileStorage::READ);
f["depthImg190"] >> m;
f.release();
```

but i am facing an exception  "Opencv Errorr: Bad argument < Unknown array type > in cv::read, file ........\opencv\modules\core\persistence.cpp, line 5535".

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: one of the problems is, that above xml is a serialized *IplImage* , not a cv::Mat. it's not only the "opencv-image" part, width<->cols, height <-> rows, etc. if that's legacy data, you'll have no other chance, than cvLoad(yukk). if you're actually *writing* this, you should change *that* part in the 1st place.

Comment: @berak you are very right and the problem is i am not writing this data. I am just using this data set for my research work and i have to use this at any cost. I'v done all, but here i am stuck is when i do use cvLoad in a loop to get files read through
    IplImage* depth=(IplImage*)cvLoad(getPath(filename));
where getPath(filename) is returning "data\\depth\\depthImg190.xml"
, but cvLoad is not reading file properly but when i use
   IplImage* depth=(IplImage*)cvLoad("data\\depth\\depthImg190.xml"); it is reading properly.

Comment: what can help me here, i am not getting if it is working when i gave file as hard code char but not working with just a variable.

Comment: you might want to print out the filename in the variable, and see if it is the same (probably some directory in front missing)

Comment: Exactly what i am saying, i have variable filename and it is printing out "data\\depth\\depthImg190.xml" using cout but it is not reading file, but when i give hard coded path s parameter to cvLoad, file is not getting read.

Comment: If yo want to see, i can show you cpp file and xml file.

Comment: Last resort available here :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611222/2836621

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is some documentation that you could use like: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html

In any case the answer to your problem is easy:

```
FileStorage fs("file.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat image;

fs["depthImg190"] >> image;

(...)

fs.release();
```

It should work!

Comment: Hey!
I'v tried this but i am facing an error
"Opencv Errorr: Bad argument < Unknown array type > in cv::read, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\persistence.cpp, line 5535"

I am very much new to opencv, will you please help me get out of this? I have to read this xml ASAP for my research. thank you

Comment: i need to read this xml ASAP, as i am new to opencv please guide me as a very basic student for opencv. thank you

Comment: If it wasn't successful then I ask you to put more information about your problem so we can help you: the code that you are using and the structure of your xml document.

Comment: I am using the same code that you suggested and facing an exception that i added in my comment above. and the over all structure of my xml file is also given in the post. I am also using "cvLoad" function to read xml 
    CvMat* A1 = (CvMat*)cvLoad("depthImg190.xml");
it is running successful but i am new to c++ and opencv and don't know how to get "data" from A1. Anyhow applying breaker points i have seen data is getting read, all now i want to get this matrix to write the image using imwrite command. Can you look into this?