# How to use loop to Process all images present in folder in visual C++

Tags: .net, opencv, visual-c++, c++-cli

Goal : Perform operation on all images one by one present in folder 

till now : got name of first file using `objOpenFileDialog->ShowDialog();` and then 
`System::String^ imgName = objFileDialog->FileName;` 

 
problem : 
1. **blank image.data** by `Mat image = imread("imgName", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);` 
2. How to use loop to reach up to last image (image names are in numbers with special characters)?

Comment: but you do know, that you can't imread() with a System::String^ ?

Comment: I had doubt over '^', but unable to resolve.Then how can i get "image.jpg" ?

Comment: you will have to use a c++ std::string, const char* or cv::String. opencv won't support managed System::String types. do yourself a favour, and have a clear watershed between your managed/forms code, and the opencv code.

Comment: But, objFileDIalog->FileName return type is String^.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535662/how-to-read-files-in-sequence-from-a-directory-in-opencv/26536198#26536198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem as you and got a way to fix it but do not know if it is the right way to do it.

```
char * filepath = new char[100];
for(int j=0; j<n_images ; j++) // for all images
{
    sprintf(filepath,"/home/datasets/img-%i.png",j); // changing the path
    Mat image = imread(filepath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

your code here (.....)

}
```

My images are named "img-0.png", "img-1.png", "img-2.png", etc. You can adapt the code to the name you want.

Run time number of images version:

```
Mat image = imread("/home/datasets/img-0.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
int j=0;
while(image.data)
{
    sprintf(filename,"/home/datasets/img-%i.png",j);
    image = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    if(!image.data )
    {
        // no more images
        break;
    }

    ( your code... )

    j++;
}
```

Comment: what if you don't know number of images present in folder ?
int n_images should be set at runtime... but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me

```
String folderpath = "images/*.jpg" //images is the folder where the images are stored
vector<String> filenames;
cv::glob(folderpath, filenames);

for (size_t i=0; i<filenames.size(); i++)
{
    Mat im = imread(filenames[i]);
    ... your processing here
}
```

From : https://answers.opencv.org/question/88141/how-to-loop-over-all-the-images-using-opencv-300-and-c/