# read some images randomly using a percentage in OpenCv 3.0.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, opencv3.0

i would to devllop a SVM classifier,for that i have images, and i would to read 80% for training, and 20% for test randomly, using OpenCv 3.0.0 and C++.
can you help me please.
my images are in the same folder.

Comment: Use "glob" to get a vector of strings with the path of all images. Random shuffle the vector, and load the needed number of images

Comment: note that i read all names of my images, and i put it in a file, than i load it, and now i would to load only 80% of them for training, but not only the fist ones .

Comment: i have a nother question please, how can i spicify 80% of the size of my list, and any library i must include (for the shuffle random, and for the percentage) ?

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: yes, i tried but i couldn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- read all files in the specified folder with OpenCV [glob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536198/5008845) function. You'll save all filenames into a `std::vector<std::string>`,
- `std::random_shuffle` the vector of file names
- Keep only the first XX% names of the shuffled vector
- Do something with your images

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Read all .png files from the specified folder
    std::string folder = "D:/SO/img/*.png";
    std::vector<std::string> filenames;
    cv::glob(folder, filenames);

    // Random shuffle
    std::random_shuffle(filenames.begin(), filenames.end());

    // Keep 80%
    float how_many = 0.80;
    size_t N = filenames.size() * how_many;

    // Do something with N random images
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // Load and show image
        cv::Mat3b img = cv::imread(filenames[i]);
        cv::imshow("Img", img);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: very good, thank you very much, I'm so happy for your help. now can you tell me please how can i read the rest of images (20%) for the test part, without repete (i mean an image used for train, must be not used for test) ? please

Comment: Just use images from index `N` to `filenames.size()`. And try to study a little how C++ works

Comment: thank you verry much, i did it.

Comment: Miki , can you answer my quesion in the link below        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655182/roc-curve-in-opencv3-0-0

Comment: can you please help me, I want an answer for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876093/no-lineaire-svm-in-opencv-3-0-0