# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. when using glob from opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, glob, access-violation

I wonder what is wrong here?

```
String path = "Z:\\Cs585\\HW2\\draft\\hw2-kim\\hw2-kim\\assets\\*.jpg";
//String path = "assets\\*.jpg";
vector<String> fn;
glob(path, fn, false);
vector<Mat> handTemplates;
for (auto filename : fn){
    Mat temp_hand = imread(filename);
    handTemplates.push_back(temp_hand);
}
```

It crashes and gives access violation at `vector<Mat> handTemplates;` line.

basically, `main.cpp` is in `Z:\Cs585\HW2\draft\hw2-kim\hw2-kim` directory and images which I want to open using imread in batch fashion are in the folder inside it named `assets`.

Any thoughts?
[image]

[image]

Update: 
However, accessing images one by one works:

```
vector<Mat> handTemplates;

Mat fist_hand = imread("assets\\fist.jpg");
handTemplates.push_back(fist_hand);

Mat full_hand = imread("assets\\full_hand.jpg");
handTemplates.push_back(full_hand);

Mat thumbs_up_hand = imread("assets\\thumbs_up.jpg");
handTemplates.push_back(thumbs_up_hand);

Mat victory_hand = imread("assets\\victory.jpg");
handTemplates.push_back(victory_hand);
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? If that is the case, I think you are taking ATL/MFC String class instead of [std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536198/501196) or [cv::String](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html)

Comment: so what makes it correct? can you correct it in a line?

Comment: Is `path` right?  You only have one backslash before the filename wildcard.

Comment: Odds are `String` is `cv::String`, which should be OK, but it could be colliding with `System::String` if the .Net library's been pulled in. @1201 's on a good path, though.

Comment: I'll try this one and let you know. As far as remember, I also tried cv::String. I know that glob method requires cv::String.

Comment: "Ill try this one and let you know" Over a year later, no word from OP. Rip.