# How to read files in sequence from a directory in OpenCV and use it for processing?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, glob

When I try to compile this piece of code I am getting this error-

> error: no matching function for call to 'glob(std::__cxx11::string&, std::vector >&, bool)'
>            glob (folder, filename, false);
>                                         ^

This is the code I used:

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <glob.h>

    string folder = "/home/ragesh/C++ /calibration_laptop/images/*.jpg";
    vector <string> filename;
    glob(folder, filename, false);
    if(count < filename.size())
    {

        img = imread(filename[count]);
        if(img.empty())
        {
            cout << "\nimage loading failed.....!"<<"\n";
            return 0;
        }
        imshow("image", img);
        cvtColor ( img,gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );// gray scale the source image
        vector<Point2f> corners; //this will be filled by the detected corners

        bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(gray, boardSize, corners, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
        count ++;
    }
```

Comment: `#include <string>`

Comment: @MarkSetchell  Even when I added ( folder.c_str() )'code' I am getting the same error.

Comment: Looking at the signature of `glob`, I'd say the problem is with the second parameter. You can construct a `cv::String` from a `std::string`, but that won't help with a non-const reference to a vector...

Comment: As usual, an actual [MCVE] wouldn't hurt -- missing includes, missing namespace qualifiers, no `main()`, code outside a function... what's that supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `CV::String` instead of `std::string`.

Add `#include "cvstd.hpp"`, then

```
cv::String new_folder_string(folder).
std::vector<cv::String> new_filename_vector.
glob(new_folder_string, new_filename_vector, false);
```

Some info [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaf91b7f383218e2d3f760939140942297)(glob function), [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html)(String class in OpenCV), [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/db0/peopledetect_8cpp-example.html#a26)(example of use of glob with cv::String) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26536198/2296663)(berak's suggestion).

EDIT: I forgot to mention that you need to switch also `filename` from `std::string` to `cv::String`.

Comment: The code worked when filename was switched from std::string to cv::String.

Answer (score 4):

The function [`cv::glob`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaf91b7f383218e2d3f760939140942297) has the following signature:

```
void cv::glob(cv::String pattern, std::vector<cv::String>& result, bool recursive = false)
```

Since `pattern` is passed by value, and a `cv::String` can be [constructed from a `std::string`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html#aba22f87619091a1b6a2899d0b45a3472), the first parameter is not a problem. A temporary `cv::String` is automatically constructed.

However, the second one -- `result` -- is, since it's taken as a non-const reference. In order to fix your problem, you need to make `filename` a `std::vector<cv::String>`. Since it represents a collection of file names, I'd also suggest using plural to name it: `filenames`.

Example code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string folder("/home/ragesh/C++ /calibration_laptop/images/*.jpg");
    std::vector<cv::String> filenames;
    cv::glob(folder, filenames, false);

    // Do something with filenames...

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:**

I concluded from the signature, and the tags on your question, that you're after the OpenCV `glob` (the incomplete code sample makes that somewhat difficult). However, note that the header you included is for the [Posix `glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/glob.html) function.

There's a good chance that was another cause of problems.

For completeness, let me list the rest of the issues I find with your code sample:

- Missing includes (opencv, string)
- Missing namespace qualifiers (`std::` or `cv::` -- [avoid `using namespace` at top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice))
- No `main()`
- Code outside a function
- A bunch of other unrelated code after the relevant bit, which I won't analyze further (but roughly 80% of your code sample is irrelevant).

Comment: OP has also included POSIX `glob.h`. I think it should be pointed out that there's a difference between these.

Comment: @zindarod Sure. I kinda ignored it due to the rather poor quality of the code sample.