# How can I convert .xml files which contain image information to jpeg or png

Tags: opencv

My task is to prepare the data for a Human Action Detection algorithm. To sum up I have been given some image .xml files (that have been taken with a Kinect sensor) that I want to convert to jpeg or png to be readable from the algorithm. I assume I have to use OpenCV.

I'm sure it's a beginners question but I've searched the internet and found nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<depthImg190 type_id="opencv-image">
  <width>320</width>
  <height>240</height>
  <origin>top-left</origin>
  <layout>interleaved</layout>
  <dt>w</dt>
  <data>
    0 0 0 0 27120 27384 27120 27120 27384 27120 27120 27120 27120 27384
    27384 27664 27664 27944 27944 27664 27664 27944 27944 27944 28224
    27944 27944 28224 28224 28224 28224 28520 28816 29120 29120 29120
    29120 29120 29120 29120 29432 29744 30072 30072 29744 29744 30072
    30072 30072 30400 30400 30736 30736 31080 31080 31080 31440 31440
    31440 31440 31800 31800 31800 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

    0 0 0 0 27120 27120 27120 27120 27384 27384 27384 27384 27384 27384
    27664 27944 27944 27944 27944 27944 27944 27944 27944 27944 28224
    27944 28224 28224 28224 28224 28224 28520 29120 29120 29120 29120
    29120 29120 29120 29432 29432 29744 29744 30072 30072 30072 30072
    30400 30400 30400 30400 30736 30736 31080 31080 31440 31440 31440
    31440 31440 31800 31800 31800 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 27120 27120 27120 27120 27664 27384 27384 27384 27120 27384
    27664 27944 27944 27944 27944 27664 27944 27944 27944 27944 28224
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read xml file with type\_id opencv-image using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421473/read-xml-file-with-type-id-opencv-image-using-opencv)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a **complete** file please?

Comment: http://cvrc.ece.utexas.edu/datasets.html in UTKinect - Action. This is where I downloaded them from @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really ugly hack, but it allows you to convert the XML file into a [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) file which you can easily read with OpenCV, or ImageMagick, or Photoshop, or convert into a **PNG** or **JPEG**:

```
#!/bin/bash

xml=$1

# Get width and height of image
w=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//width"  -v . -n "$xml")
h=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//height" -v . -n "$xml")

# Generate PPM header - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format
printf "P2\n$w $h\n65535\n" > image.ppm

# Append ASCII image data
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//data" -v . -n "$xml"  >> image.ppm
```

You would save it in your HOME directory as `xml2ppm` and make it executable (just one time) with:

```
chmod +x $HOME/xml2ppm
```

You would run it with:

```
$HOME/xml2ppm someFile.xml
```

[image]

---

You could also remove the dependency on `xmlstarlet` and make something even uglier and hackier, if you assume all the images are 320x240 and extract the pixel data from the XML using `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate PPM header - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format
# and follow with ASCII data from XML file embedded in <data>...</data> tags

xml=$1

awk '
  BEGIN      {print "P2\n320 240\n65535\n"}
  /<data>/   {flag=1; next}
  /<\/data>/ {exit}
  flag
  ' "$xml" > image.ppm
```

---

You can also convert the resulting **PPM** file to **PNG** with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick image.ppm result.png    # convert to PNG
magick image.ppm result.jpg    # convert to JPEG
```

Use `convert` in place of `magick` if your **ImageMagick** is v6 or older.

**Keywords**: XML, xmlstarlet, Kinect, OpenCV, opencv-storage, depthImg190, opencv-image

Comment: wow! It worked.Thank you very much. So the reason that the files are in xml is for them to be able to can be read from different applications?

Comment: @DimitrisOikonomou Sorry, I have no idea why anyone would choose to use such an obscure format - you would have to ask the publishers of the info. I can't see anything in the files that cannot be stored in a normal PNG or TIFF or indeed PPM file - all of which can store 16-bit greyscale or colour data.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it works and you don't get anything better :-)

Comment: I'm new to this. I'm still trying to understand what the numbers, in the .xml, really represent, though. Thank you very much!!! :-D

Comment: Hopefully you can see the width and height on 4th and 5th line. Then the numbers in the `<data>` section are just grey values of the pixels on a scale of 0..65535, i.e. 16-bit. They are stored in rows, top row first, gradually working down the image. HTH.